# Running Rasa project in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

As far as I understand from Rasa 1 onwards there is mainly the "actions" that needs to be run over terminal and then the Rasa shell or interactive, etc.

How do you run this using PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this sequence, if you want to debug in PyCharm:

1. Make sure that your actions endpoint server is running in one of the terminals.
2. Attach the process using Run -> Attach to Process...
3. Make sure that your actions class has required breakpoints
4. Make sure that your action class in triggered when you chat

You will be able to debug as usual when the breakpoint is hit.

Answer (score -1):

You can open multiple [terminal sessions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/terminal-emulator.html#new_session) in Pycharm.  Open one session to run `rasa run actions` and then another terminal session to run (for instance) `rasa shell --endpoints endpoints.yml`

Comment: In that case do we get breakpoints in code? I tried but did not get it.

Comment: You won't, try Debug Server. It can work locally as well https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html#remote-debug-config